# Sql Server xml column with Entity Framework - how to keep insignificant whitespaces

Tags: sql, xml, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

Sql server 2005 (even 2008) strips the insignificant whitespaces by default.  To keep one can use the CONVERT funtction with the last argument as '1' ([Ref. Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/archive/2005/09/12/464145.aspx)).  How can we do the same thing in Entity Framework?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for the problem. You can set the xml attribute 'xml:space=preserve" at the document level.  Both Sql server 2005 and 2008 respect the attribute setting and keep the whitespaces.  it was a pleasant surprise.  Unfortunately, MSDN documentation does not explicitly say this.